# Perl Facebook::Graph Post to Facebook Page as Page, not as Admin

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api, perl-module

Using the Perl module, Facebook::Graph, I have created some basic perl code that can post to my own wall.  I can share a photo on my own wall.  I can also post a simple wall message to one of the pages for which I am an admin.  However, when I try to post a photo to the page, it posts as me, not as the page.

Here is the sample code that posts as me, to the Facebook page.  I need it to post as the Page, not as me.

```
# previously, I obtained my Page's accesstoken, and other credentials
# including the Facebook Page ID

my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new(
    app_id  =>      $facebook_application_id,
    secret  =>      $facebook_application_secret
);

$fb->access_token($facebook_accesstoken);

my $rstring = $fb
    ->add_photo
    ->to($facebookPageID)
    ->set_message('Look at this really cool photo!')
    ->set_source('./raw_image_example.jpg')
    ->publish
    ->as_string;

print "$rstring\n\n";
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a post to the wall of a Facebook page, as if it is being posted BY the page, not by me.

I am trying to do that with the CPAN module, Facebook::Graph, located here: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::Graph](http://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook%3a%3aGraph)

I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out.  Any help would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same trouble, so let me share what I did step by step so it might benefit other people:

1. After going to developers.facebook.com to create an app, you
   go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. There, on the top menu named "Graph API Explorer" you select the app
   you just created
3. Then, on the righthand side, there is another menu named "Get
   Token", in which you select "Get Access Token", then a pop-up window
   will appear, you to the extended
   permissions tab, and check "publish_pages" and "manage_pages"
   options and click on "Get Access Token". It will pop-up a window
   asking you to confirm you want to grant access to this app. It will
   produce a long token.
4. Then, you select the menu Get Token again, and you will find in this
   menu the list of the pages you manage, select the one you want and
   it will show its related access token.
5. Now the token received is only temporary like 2 hours or something.
   You want something that last 60 days and renewable, so from your
   server you do a curl request: 
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=$facebook_application_id&client_secret=$facebook_application_secret&fb_exchange_token=$facebook_accesstoken

   Facebook will output something like this:

access_token=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&expires=5184971

6. Then, you can post as your page using your fine code.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable manage_pages permission to get a code.
2. Submit code to get user access token for your account (you are manager or content_creactor) for query everythings.
3. Queried your account by calling /me/accounts, you will get page access token. one account can manage many pages. So use JSON to choose which one do you want.
4. Use those page access token to post msg or photo as normal. https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
   (note that it is not /feed) since page access token contain the ID already.